# css for animated image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to create an css for image ie height and width. how can create?

```
<div id="toHide" class="pb-text-align-center">
<img src="img/load.gif" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"/>
<form wicket:id="safeForm" class="clearfix" />
</div>

.pf-text-align-center, .pb-text-align-center { text-align: center; }

<script type="text/javascript">
  var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
  $('#toHide').doTimeout(1000, function() { $('#toHide').find('#safeForm35').submit();});
</script>
```

Issue: dynamic animation action is not happening in IE. it may resolve by doing correct height and width. How can i see what is the required height and width? and other details?

**EDIT**

> Answer:

HTML source code:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript"> 
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); 
    document.getElementById('toHide').style.display ="";
    $('#toHide').doTimeout(1000, function() { 
        $('#toHide').find('#safeForm34').submit(); 
        document.getElementById('myAnimatedImage').src = "../../img/load.gif"; 
        });
</SCRIPT>
```

html:

```
  <div id="toHide" class="pb-text-align-center">
    <img src="img/load.gif" id='myAnimatedImage' style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"/>
    <form wicket:id="safeForm" class="clearfix" />
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any dynamic animation action in this code - what do you mean?

Comment: I would guess that he means load.gif is an animated gif. Not what I would call dynamic, though....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bad news for you - you're hitting a known bug in IE.

In IE, if you load an animated GIF, but it's invisible when it loads, then the animation won't work when you make it visible.

The work-around is to load the image at the time you need to display by setting the `src` attribute, rather than pre-loading it and making it visible.

Reference: http://www.norio.be/blog/2008/09/animated-gif-not-working-internet-explorer

Comment: thanks you so much, it solved my long days problem. thanks for the link also. updated my final output in main question.